# Parse break one-to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, parsing

How do you break relationships in Parse database?

I'm writing an application, which revolves around Person and Device objects.

A person can rent multiple devices, but a device can only be rented by one person (one-to-many relationship).

I can create a relationship by setting **device.person** to **person.object** (person.object is the PFObject, Person just encapsulates that object).

But I don't know how to delete the relationship.

I'll post code if it's needed, but I'm unsure which part would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting a `PFObject` property value with `setObject:forKey:` then you should be unsetting with `removeObjectForKey:`.